# Drop down model data not being set and ng-change issue using keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a drop down on my html:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="ApplicationForm" name="ApplicationForm" class="form-control" ng-disabled="NoForm == '1'"
        ng-model="Model.ApplicationForm" ng-options="Forms.FormCode as Forms.FormDescription for Forms in Data.HOSeleForms" ng-change="SetAppForm"
        required>
    </select>
```

When I select the drop down using mouse, ng-change always fires and model data ModelData.ApplicationForm updates correctly. But when I use keyboard and select the drop down, model data only update on first time drop down selection change and ng-change fires only for the first time but the second time neither model data updates nor ng-change fires.

Again, If I change the selected item in the dropdown more than twice. It starts updating the modeldata ApplicationForm.

what could be the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ie9 browser bug and not an angular bug.

This works.

```
theApp.directive("select", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      require: "?ngModel",
      scope: false,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) {
          return;
        }
        element.bind("keyup", function() {
          element.triggerHandler("change");
        })
      }
   }
})
```